# Centering multiline inline-block with dynamic width

Tags: html, css

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>large test <br /> block #1</div>
        <div>large test <br /> block #2</div>
        <div>large test <br /> block #3</div>
        <div>large test <br /> block #4</div>
        <div>large test <br /> block #5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div {
    background: #f00;
    text-align: center;
}

div > div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    background: #0f0;
    text-align: left;
}

div > div > div {
    background: #00f;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/wnV3H/
You can see when the width is large enough to have all the content in one single line, it works fine. But when the content wrapped into two lines or more, the second div takes the whole width and is not centering. Like this:

```
#1 #2 #3 #4 (blank)
#5          (blank)
```

What I want is:

```
(blank) #1 #2 #3 #4 (blank)
(blank) #5          (blank)
```

Not this:

```
(blank) #1 #2 #3 #4 (blank)
(blank)     #5      (blank)
```

Any fixes for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it might help adding classes to the divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do any better than you currently have you'll have to use javascript.

Essentially you'll have to calculate the `max-width` of the parent container, calculate the width of each child element, add together the widths of the children until you reach the parent's max width (moving any children that don't fit completely to the next line), then set the parent's width to the sum of the children's widths that you just calculated

A demo (using other HTML) can be seen [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yXxD6/55/), you can apply the approach to your situation. More than likely this is more work than you're wanting to do and you'll have to accept the slight space in between

On a side note, classes help organize your code, keep it cleaner, and make it not mess up similar situations on your page. You should use them

Comment: Yeah I know, I just use those div > div > div for testing purpose. :P
And I want #5 to be in the middle left instead of middle. Look at the question for more details. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @Mygod "Middle left" doesn't make sense and is up to an individual's interpretation. I made it how your question said, the question doesn't clarify anything

Comment: I mean the #5 one should be shown under #1 if there are four elements in a row instead of showing below #2 and #3.

Comment: @Mygod Then it's [exactly the code you gave...](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/wnV3H/2/)

Comment: Yes but I want the whole block to be in the center. Sorry if I didn't clarify that.

Comment: @Mygod Updated my answer to fit the new conditions